# Discord.py How To Delete Every Text-Channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command that allows the user to delete every Text-Channel in their server. I've got an error when running this piece of code.

```
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'delete_text_channel'
```

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        guild.delete_text_channel(channel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `await channel.delete()`.

As your error message sais, the object `'Guild'` has no attribute `'delete_text_channel'`
The correct way would be:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.delete()
```

Alternatively, you can add a reason why you deleted the message, which would show up in the audit log:

```
channel.delete("Because I can")
```

More information [`here`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete).

#### Be careful

`guild.channels` calls all channels, not only Textchannels.
To call Textchannels only, use `guild.text_channels`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `await channel.delete()` with this example code:

```
@client.command()
async def delete_channels(ctx):
    [await channel.delete() for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels]
```

You can simply use that.